# JAVA_HOME incorrectly set |JVM terminated exit code 2

Tags: hadoop, windows-8.1, java-home

While formatting the name node, I'm getting this error:

> "JAVA_HOME incorrectly set."

My `JAVA_HOME` was `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45`. As per some solutions on the net, I copied the Java folder to the `C:\` and directly
changed env variable to `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45` both on `windows` and `hadoop env.sh`.

This made the namenode formatting but the eclipse on the windows was no more working showing error:

> "JVM terminated exit code 2"

This error persists even after setting the `JAVA_PATH JAVA_HOME` correctly.
Where should I have gone wrong?

Comment: Thats good you found a tutorial on the internet but is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45` the actual path to *your* jdk ?

Comment: Yes that was my actual path.What I did was just brought my java folder out of the Program Files and pasted it in the C drive directly so the path is simple.